# Update MongoDB collection using $toLower

Tags: mongodb

I have an existing MongoDB collection containing user names. The user names contain both lower case and upper case letters.

I want to update all the user names so they only contain lower case letters.

I have tried this script, but it didn't work

```
db.myCollection.find().forEach(
 function(e) {
 e.UserName = $toLower(e.UserName);
 db.myCollection.save(e);
 }
)
```

Comment: *Didn't work* == *Nothing changed*?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

MongoDB does not have a concept of `$toLower` as a command. The solution is to run a big `for` loop over the data and issue the updates individually.

You can do this in any driver or from the shell:

```
db.myCollection.find().forEach(
  function(e) {
    e.UserName = e.UserName.toLowerCase();
    db.myCollection.save(e);
  }
)
```

You can also replace the save with an atomic update:

```
db.myCollection.update({_id: e._id}, {$set: {UserName: e.UserName.toLowerCase() } })
```

Again, you could also do this from any of the drivers, the code will be very similar.

---

EDIT: Remon brings up a good point. The `$toLower` command does exist as part of the aggregation framework, but this has nothing to do with updating. The documentation for updating is [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating).

Comment: Actually as of 2.1 MongoDB does have $toLower but it's an expression within the aggregation framework only ;)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I ended up writing a console application using C#, instead of trying to figure out script for the shell.

Comment: Have you tested the 2nd form (atomic update with `$set`)? I couldn't get it to work (no errors were shown, but no documents were actually updated). I'm new to JavaScript, so I'm probably just making a rookie mistake.

Comment: Yeah, the update works inside the function(e), instead of the two lines in the example above.

Comment: Late to the party here but what is it that makes the update atomic vs the save, given that the value of e.UserName and e._id is in memory already?
Is it just that it is atomic with respect to mongo's internals?

Comment: @DrewR I guess he means that changes to any **other** fields will not be clobbered, because it just updates `UserName`.  If `UserName` has changed, however, I think the change will be clobbered!

Comment: Since `.save` is deprecated, in DocumentDB which isn't up to 4.2 yet, this would look like `db. myCollection.find().forEach(doc => {db.myCollection.updateOne({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {UserName: doc.UserName.toLowerCase()}});});`

Answer (score 70):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update) can accept an aggregation pipeline, finally allowing the update of a field based on its own value:

```
// { username: "Hello World" }
db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  [{ $set: { username: { $toLower: "$username" } } }]
)
// { username: "hello world" }
```

- The first part `{}` is the match query, filtering which documents to update (in this case all documents).
- The second part `[{ $set: { username: { $toLower: "$username" } } }],` is the update aggregation pipeline (note the squared brackets signifying the use of an aggregation pipeline):

  - [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) is a new aggregation operator which in this case modifies the value for `"username"`.
  - Using [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/), we modify the value of `"username"` by its lowercase version.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only solution that works for large dataset.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked make sure to use an array so mongodb knows to use an aggreggation

Answer (score 2):

Very similar solution but this worked me in new mongo 3.2
Execute the following in Mongo Shell or equivalent DB tools like MongoChef!

```
db.tag.find({hashtag :{ $exists:true}}).forEach(
 function(e) {
   e.hashtag = e.hashtag.toLowerCase();
   db.tag.save(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With the accepted solution I know its very trivial to do the same for an array of elements, just in case

```
db.myCollection.find().forEach(
   function(e) {
      for(var i = 0; i < e.articles.length; i++) { 
          e.articles[i] = e.articles[i].toLowerCase(); 
      }
      db.myCollection.save(e); 
   }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but the below answer works very well with mongo 3.4 and above
First get only those records which have different case and update only those records in bulk.
The performance of this query is multifold better

```
var bulk = db.myCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0
db.myCollection.find({userId:{$regex:'.*[A-Z]'}}).forEach(function(e) {
 var newId = e.userId.toLowerCase();   
    bulk.find({_id:e._id}).updateOne({$set:{userId: newId}})
    count++
    if (count % 500 === 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.myCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
        count = 0;
    }
})
if (count > 0)  bulk.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to make sure the field exists for all entries in your collection.  If not you will need an if statement, like the following:

```
if (e.UserName) e.UserName = e.UserName.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: did u mean
   `if (e.UserName)`
instead of 
    `if (e.username)` 
?