# mongoose | update all documents according to a field in each document

Tags: javascript, mongoose

i have a collection which i would like to update all of it's documents according to field `email` and convert it to lower case.

```
const addressBookSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
});
const addressBook = mongoose.model("address_book", addressBookSchema)
```

i'm trying to do the following:

```
addressBook.update({}, {$set: {email: email.toLowerCase()}}, {multi: true});
```

But that doesn't work.

how do i get the email field and set it to lowercase?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423932/update-mongodb-collection-using-tolower).

Comment: @Vikig i understand how to do it on one document (then i have the `e` object as in the reference you sent). question is how do it do it for all

Comment: Also, what is `addressBook` here, it should be a `Model`.

Comment: @ViKiG yes you are right. i just didn't write the whole code. but i've updated my question. thx

Answer (score 2):

By the below method you are able to update multiple document with lower case aggregate function.

```
db.addressBook.updateMany(
    {},
    [{$set : {email :{ $toLower: "$email" } }}],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For doing it on all documents,

```
addressBook.find({}, {email: 1})
    .exec((err, docs) => {
        if (err || docs == undefined || docs.length == 0)
            ;
        else {
            docs.forEach((doc) => {
                 addressBook.findOneAndUpdate({_id: doc._id}, 
                                              {$set: {email: doc.email.lowercase()}})
                 .exec();
            });
       }
    });
```

Comment: it's a big collection (over 400,000 documents).
i'm looking for a solution to do this in one operation

Comment: Do you want to run it over all of the documents.

Comment: This will work. but i'm looking to do this in one operation with `update` on the whole collection

Comment: there is no such work around, where you can simply apply `$toLower` to update. You have to fetch the old values, to replace them with lower case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have such a large dataset, you should use the [bulkWrite()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) function

```
addressBook.bulkWrite([
  {
    updateMany: {
      filter: {},
      update: { email: email.lowercase()}
    }
  },
]).then(handleResult);
```

Comment: where is `doc` defined?

Comment: same issue: `email` is not defined - and so you can't perform toLowerCase() on it.